# Saving WordPress Posts, Pages, Widgets return 404 Page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Wordpress version: 4.9.6

Theme: BeTheme

If I use any inline styling anywhere in the Page Editor, Post Editor and  text Widget when I try to preview a page or post or try to save the widget WordPress redirects me to the 404 Page.

First I considered this as an issue of `.htaccess` file so I tried the followings:

1. update permalinks
2. delete the old `.htaccess` file and re-create automatically by updating the permalinks
3. created fresh `.htaccess` file and palced rewrite-rules according to some tutorials
4. Deactivated Plugins one by one and Re-Activated 
   But I realized this issue is not related to .htaccess file.

For Confirmation I created a page with no content or simple content with Text only and it was successfully updated 
When I tried to embed google maps code generated from [Embed Google Map](https://www.embedgooglemap.net/) website and tried to update the page I received 404 Page.

Comment: Where is this hosted? It's conceivable that your host has some mod security rules that are getting triggered, preventing that content from being `$_POST`-ed.

Comment: Thanks @cale_b it was host which was triggering security rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was with Mod Security Rules, I visited the CPanel of the Hosting and Disabled the ModSecurity and then Updated the Page and Problem was resolved. Though disabling the ModSecurity puts the website on security risk but after making changes to the website and enabling again works fine.